# Validate and order a thresholds list like russian dolls

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a list of thresholds like `[(10,100),(60,75),(50,70),(20,90)]` 
And I need to order that list like russian dolls, the highest contains the next and so on.
How would be the optimus way to validate this list? The code below is my current approach, but I'm think it could be better.

```
public class MThresholds implements Comparable< MThresholds>{

  private Double threshold_low = null;
  private Double threshold_high = null;

  public MThresholds(Double thresholdLow, Double thresholdHigh) {
      this.threshold_low = thresholdLow;
      this.threshold_high = thresholdHigh;
  }

  @Override
  public int compareTo(MThresholds thresholds) {
    return this.getThreshold_high().compareTo(thresholds.getThreshold_high());
  }
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws BadRequestException {
        List<MThresholds> thresholdsList = new ArrayList<>();
        thresholdsList.add(new MThresholds(42.0, 48.0));
        thresholdsList.add(new MThresholds(30.0, 60.0));
        thresholdsList.add(new MThresholds(20.0, 70.0));
        thresholdsList.add(new MThresholds(40.0, 50.0));
        thresholdsList.add(new MThresholds(10.0, 80.0));

        thresholdsList.sort(Collections.reverseOrder());

        for (int index = 0; index < thresholdsList.size() - 1; index++) {
            MThresholds currentThreshold = thresholdsList.get(index);
            MThresholds nextThreshold = thresholdsList.get(index + 1);
            if (!(currentThreshold.getThreshold_high() > nextThreshold.getThreshold_high() && currentThreshold.getThreshold_low() < nextThreshold.getThreshold_low())) {
                throw new Exception("Hard threshold should contain the soft one");
            }

        }
    }
```

So, my idea is order the list by one of the fields (threshold high value), then iterate the list and check if the current threshold contain the next one. This way works, but looks a bit silly to me. Any way to improve this?

Comment: Could you provide input and output?

Comment: The input is the list from a REST endpoint and I have to validate it before persist on DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing particularly silly about your code. You could however, take the if statement and move it into the `MThresholds` class as a method on the object to check if one threshold is contained by another.

```
   public boolean contains(MThresholds that) {
        return that.threshold_low >= threshold_low && that.threshold_high <= threshold_high;
    }
```

And you could then either modify your comparator or create a standalone comparator that has the expectation that all thresholds contain or are contained by another threshold and will fail for any overlaps in thresholds.

```
    @Override
    public int compareTo(MThresholds thresholds) {
        if (contains(thresholds)) {
            return 1;
        }

        if (thresholds.contains(this)) {
            return -1;
        }

        throw new IllegalStateException("Thresholds overlap");
    }
```

Putting it all together it might look something like this:

```
public class MThresholds {

    private static class NoIntersectionComparator implements Comparator<MThresholds> {
        @Override
        public int compare(MThresholds o1, MThresholds o2) {
            if (o1.contains(o2)) {
                return 1;
            }

            if (o2.contains(o1)) {
                return -1;
            }

            throw new IllegalStateException("Thresholds overlap");
        }
    }

    private final Double threshold_low;
    private final Double threshold_high;

    public MThresholds(Double thresholdLow, Double thresholdHigh) {
        this.threshold_low = thresholdLow;
        this.threshold_high = thresholdHigh;
    }

    public boolean contains(MThresholds that) {
        return that.threshold_low >= threshold_low && that.threshold_high <= threshold_high;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        List<MThresholds> thresholdsList = new ArrayList<>();
        thresholdsList.add(new MThresholds(42.0, 48.0));
        thresholdsList.add(new MThresholds(30.0, 60.0));
        thresholdsList.add(new MThresholds(20.0, 70.0));
        thresholdsList.add(new MThresholds(40.0, 50.0));
        thresholdsList.add(new MThresholds(10.0, 80.0));
        thresholdsList.sort(new NoIntersectionComparator().reversed());
    }
}
```